# Use of Bayesian formula in R?

Tags: r, bayesian

I am looking for a package in R that can help me to calculate the posterior probability of an event.  Is there any?

Alright, I am working on such a data set

age education   grade   pass
group1      primary 50  no
group2  tertiary    20  no
group1  secondary   70  yes
group2  secondary   67  yes
group1  secondary   55  yes
group1  secondary   49  no
group1  secondary   76  yes

I have the prior probability of a student passing the exam is 0.6, Now I need to get the posterior probability of a student pass given his age , education level, and grade
I know I should get first P(age=group1| pass=yes)* P(education=primary| pass=yes)* P(grade>50 |pass=yes)
But this should be done for each case (row) and I have a date set with 1000 rows
So, I thought I can get a function helps me in this!

Comment: Snarking aside, this is an impossibly vague question.  There are *many* R packages that do various forms of Bayesian estimation; `library("sos"); findFn("Bayesian")` will give you far too many results.  This question will probably be closed soon, but if you can provide more context and details, someone might be able to help ...

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it's clear

Comment: it's much better.  Why don't you try `with(yourData,tapply(age,education,grade>50),pass,mean)/mean(pass))` and see if that gives you any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer for only one variable (education) and variable (pass):

```
# get the prior probabilities  
prior<- c(prior_no, prior_yes)

# get contingency table of values for mydata
edu_table<- with(mydata,table(mydata$pass, mydata$education))

# get the sum across (pass)
tots<- apply(edu_table,1,sum)

# create matrix of 0's
ppn<- edu_table*0  
post<- edu_table*0  

# use a loop to get the prior probabilities& posterior probabilities
for(i in 1:length(tots)){
  for( j in 1: 4){

    ppn[i,j]=edu_table[i,j]/tots[i]
    post[i,j]=prior[i]*ppn[i,j]/(prior[1]*ppn[1,j]+prior[2]*ppn[2,j])

  }
} 

ppn # probability of education=j given y=i
post # posterior probability of y=i given education=j
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many packages/functions available. You should check out the [Bayesian inference Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Bayesian.html)

Also, if your prior isn't a full distribution and is only a point estimate of a probability, you're probably not actually doing bayesian inference, just using bayes rule in a frequentist framework. Very different. But now we're getting into CrossValidated territory.